# Storing Folder+Files inside dict, optimization

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, python-3.2, os.walk

I've got a little struggle for quite a while with my method for getting a folder / file detection wich stores it inside a dictionary.

The Folder setup is the following:

```
channel / subchannel1 / 1.cfg, 2.cfg, 3.cfg
channel / subchannel2 / 4.cfg, 5.cfg, 6.cfg
```

And I want to store it in a dictionary with the subchannel as a key and the containing files as a list as of:

```
{'subchannel1': ['1.cfg', '2.cfg', '3.cfg'], 'subchannel2': ['4.cfg', '5.cfg', '6.cfg']}
```

And I've got almost as far as to accomplish that, however I feel there is a way better way to do that.
Here's my method:

```
import os

def getFiles():

    testdict = {}

    for directory, subdirectory, files in os.walk("channel"):
        for file in files:
            testdict[str(directory)] = testdict.get(str(directory),[])+[file]

    return testdict
```

However if I print that out, the dictionary has the keys:

```
'channel\\subchannel1', 'channel\\subchannel2'
```

instead of:

```
'subchannel1', 'subchannel2'
```

Calling str(subdirectory) instead of str(directory) will give me an empty list as a key, wich i honestly do not understand.
Of course i could call a str(directory).split('\\')[1] for the key to get rid of that annoying 'channel\\' but I feel there is a way smoother way to do this and I'm sure that I think far too overcomplicated.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `directory` part from `os.walk()` contains full relative path. You need to extract just the directory name from it.

Use [`os.path.basename()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) to do this.

Example:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename('channel/subchannel1')
'subchannel1'
>>> os.path.basename('channel/subchannel2')
'subchannel2'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. :) I guess that can be used for anything that it will recognize as a path. Would it be performance effective to use it for "long" (as in 10+ subfolders) paths compared to just split at the last slash?

Comment: This is a built-in API. Believe me it's optimized to it's potential already. No need to worry about large paths.